# Getting JSON data from server to listview in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQM and javascript, and i am getting this error on my page. What's wrong with it 
can someone please help me out.

ERROR:

```
    function Error() {
        [native code]
    }
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/umarF/YrKqK/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is a native javascript method, the [Error method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), and you're "alerting" it ?

Maybe if you try with one of the arguments instead

```
error: function (objAJAXRequest, strError) {
    console.log(strError);
}
```

Then you get a parseerror, as jQuery thinks it's a script, but it has "text/html" as mime type

The real issue is that not only is the mime type wrong, but it's not JSONP, it's just regular JSON served with "text/html" as a mime type

Comment: what i inferred is that i should change the header of my php file in server.. ?
or i am supposed to make some other changes too ?

Comment: You have to change the content type header to applicaton/json and if you're going to serve JSONP it has to be actual JSONP, and that means it should be wrapped in a callback function.

Comment: I have changed the header part but I am not able to understand the other JSONP part. Actually i tried this code with a json file on my hardrive and now i am tryin to use the same content of file hosted on a server by getting the json response from the php file that is connected to db over there. I just need to know how to get it working,[I am a noob] I would need to mimic this code for a couple of more times in my project.
Thanks

Comment: JSONP is JSON with Padding, which means it's wrapped in a function, as in `callback({"this" : "is", "my" : "json"});`. It's inserted as a script tag, so it's not really ajax, jQuery just neatly wraps it up as ajax, and as such there has to be a function to call when the file has loaded.

Comment: ok  and how do i return jsonp response from the server? ie the php file communicating with the mysql db... or just tell me how to get this working ?

Comment: Just wrap the json in a function, it's not that hard. `echo 'callback(' . json_encode(array) . ');'`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `JSONP` technique where it don't works. Read more about JSONP on jQuery site where there is a F[lickr API example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp).

If you will try to change type from `JSONP` to `JSON` you will get [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) error, because it will be cross domain request.